# Get api working in Postman but not with Axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I am following a tutorial from Udemy and got stuck here:

**Yelp.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL : 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses',
    headers : {
        Authorization : 
        'Bearer ****************'
    }
})
```

**SearchScreen.js**

```
const SearchScreen = () => {

    const [term, setTerm] = useState('');
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

    const searchApi = async () => {
        const response = await yelp.get('', {
            params : {
                term : term,
                location: 'san jose'
            }
        });
        setResults(response.data);
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.backgroundStyle}>
            <SearchBar 
                term = {term} 
                onTermChange = {setTerm}
                onTermSubmit = {searchApi} />

            <Text>We have found {results.length} results</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundStyle : {
        backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
        flex: 1
    }
})

export default SearchScreen
```

When **searchApi** is triggered I see this error in the console

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:114:22 in handleError
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:609:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:396:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/_EventEmitter.js:135:10 in EventEmitter#emit
```

The same Api with the same Authorization key is working in Postman. Am I missing something here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547373/cant-send-http-requests-to-localhost-backend-from-react-native-mobile-app
Please try this

Comment: Mine is not a localhost url

Comment: you can try with the `try{} catch(error){}` block in your `searchApi()` OR add `timeout: 25000` in your `axios.create`. hope it'll helps you.

Comment: Should `await yelp.get('')` really be empty? Try putting the whole URL in there, even if it isn't "necessary". Like '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost'

Answer (score 2):

If the connection is not the issue, the error is on the request and maybe the API is trying to let you know the error code but you aren't capturing it.

Implement a try/catch like this:

```js
try {
  const response = await yelp.get('', {
    params : {
        term : term,
        location: 'san jose'
    }
  });
  setResults(response.data); 
} catch (ex) {
  if (ex && ex !== undefined && ex.toString && ex.toString !== undefined) {
    // print the general exception
    console.log(ex.toString());
  }     
  if (
    ex.response &&
    ex.response !== undefined &&
    ex.response.data &&
    ex.response.data !== undefined
  ) {
    // print the exception message from axios response
    console.log(ex.response.data);
  }
}
```

Then check your console.

Answer (score 2):

@housefly

I think the difference between a postman GET request and your axios request is due to the hidden headers. Postman has internal logic to append the request type and below headers even if your didn't mention. Where as your manual query using Axios is not having sufficient header. Could you please try the below headers in your axios API call.

[image: Post Man API which contains all headers]

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the error using try catch block. If you are not getting any error then you can also check the network XHR calls in developer panel of your web browser. In the developer panel you can exactly see the API call url, headers and body as well you can see the response received from the API.

Chrome Browser -> https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/

Firefox -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

If you need further help then feel free to post the screenshot from your network panel or push your code to github to debug further.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error. See [Calling Yelp API from frontend JavaScript code running in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444777/calling-yelp-api-from-frontend-javascript-code-running-in-a-browser)

That code cannot be ran from a browser, which has CORS protection. If you have to, you can try to disable CORS using a third party browser extension or otherwise. (At your own risk!)

Comment: This answer led me to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome?answertab=trending#tab-top that was the solution for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check the XHR request in the network tab by the active developer tool. If you are getting errors in your API. If you are getting the response correct then debug your code by catching the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing one of them in header

1. cookie
2. Some custom header which server expect
3. origin
4. user-agent Might be serving added it as security purpose

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best way to compare your Axios request to Postman request is via **Postman console**.

In the console you can see (hidden) proxy settings, hidden headers, and other network info.

[image]